# How to find source of JS_Parse_Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running an Express app, and I am getting a JS_Parse_Error. I cannot figure out why. I have basically commented out all of the new code that I've written, yet I am still getting the error. Is there a way to find out what Javascript line is giving me the error?

```
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:196:18)
    at js_error (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:204:11)
    at croak (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:636:9)
    at token_error (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:644:9)
    at expect_token (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:657:9)
    at expect (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:660:36)
    at expr_atom (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1112:17)
    at maybe_unary (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1287:19)
    at expr_ops (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1322:24)
    at maybe_conditional (/home/charlie/Projects/chat/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1327:20)
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code along with the stack trace?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure what the relevant code is. I have 5 Javascript files. Even when I delete all of them, I still get the error. IS there a way to pinpoint what file is giving me the error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's more information on the `JS_Parse_Error` about the reason. Can you get that?

Answer (score 4):

This might not be relevant for you anymore, but I got this same error message - Which is not so verbose I have to say - And my problem was a comma missing.

Notice the comma missing before ng-show...

```
.container(itemscope, itemtype='http://schema.org/Person' ng-show='user')
   .row
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an array of key/value pairs.

My code looked like this:

```
- var links = {stack-overflow: "//stackoverflow.com/users/2479481/"}
```

Apparently, **you can't use hyphens in your keys without wrapping the key in quotes**.

So, to fix the problem, you can do either

```
- var links = {"stack-overflow": "//stackoverflow.com/users/2479481/"}
```

or

```
- var links = {stackoverflow: "//stackoverflow.com/users/2479481/"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that might be a problem (what was the problem in my case) are regular expressions. Make sure you create regex like this 
  new RegExp("/[^ ]+/g")
instead of 
  /[^ ]+/g

Also use var instead of let.

Hope this helps someone,

uglify-js version 1.2.6

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a pair of curly braces that needed to be removed:

```
AlertService.success(alertKey,
    param1
);
```

Instead of

```
AlertService.success(alertKey, {
    param1
});
```

Too bad that uglify-js sometimes doesn't point you to where the issue is...

Comment: Because that's actually valid JS. `{someVar}` is equivalent to `{"someVar": someVar}`. But Uglify doesn't understand that (or didn't at that moment in time). It checks the code "hey, this is valid JS, let's transform" but when it reaches that, it explodes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following code was causing the issue

```
loc8rData.locationByCoords(lat, lng)
    .then(
        response => {
            vm.message = response.data.length > 0 ? "" : "No locations found";
            vm.data = { locations: response.data };
        },
        e => {
            vm.message = "Sorry, something's gone wrong ";
            console.log(e);
        }
    );
```

To exactly pin point, uglify could not parse `"=>"`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I tried to use the object short hand notation.

Comment: Although an ld question, just adding my case here so anybody else stuck on this can consider this case.